# mysql, how to find a unique row when you are storing data horizontally in a set of data

Tags: mysql

I am storing data in userprofile say

```
userid | field_title | field_value
1      |   fname     |  JD1
1      |   lname     |  JD1
1      |   website   |  www.JD 
2      |   fname     |  JD2
2      |   lname     |  JD2
2      |   website   |  www.JD2
3      |   fname     |  JD3
3      |   lname     |  JD3
4      |   fname     |  JD4
4      |   lname     |  JD4
4      |   website   |  www.JD
```

As you can see from the above example, I am storing data horizontally.

So, the userid 1,2 and 4 has website. But, the userid 3 does not have a website.

Now, when I write a query. Say, the table name is foo

```
select * from foo where title!="website"
```

It will return me all 4.

How do I write a query to get only 3?

Comment: Hello, Welcome. Do you have any primary key in table?

Comment: What exactly do you want to query from MySQL? What do you want with `title != "website"`? Please edit your question to include the current query you have, the result you currently get and the result you actually want.

Comment: @Progman, I want to write a query to get only set of IDs where ID does not contain title = website.

Comment: @SonamTripathi, no the table does not have any pimary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to look for users where **none** of their entries has the `field_title` of `'website'`. This can be achieved with a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo f1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM foo f2
                  WHERE field_title = 'website' AND f1.userid = f2.userid)
```

Output:

```
userid  field_title     field_value
3       fname           JD3
3       lname           JD3
```

Comment: Let me try this. You are right, I am looking for IDs where not of their entries has the field_title of 'website'

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary key in your table then please try,assuming here **id**

```
SELECT f1.userid 
FROM   foo f1 
       LEFT JOIN foo f2 
              ON ( f1.userid = f2.userid 
                   AND f1.id < f2.id ) 
WHERE  f2.id IS NULL 
       AND f1.field_title != "website";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table called `user` that stored one user per row you can do this:

```
SELECT u.id from user u 
LEFT JOIN user_attributes ua 
 ON (u.id = ua.id AND ua.field_title='website')
WHERE ua.field_title IS NULL
```

Since a `LEFT JOIN` guarantees you have at least noe row for each user regardless if the `ON` clause matched having a `ON` clause that matches on something you don't want and then have a `WHERE` clause where one of the fields that normally isn't `NULL` gets filtered on them being `NULL` will return one row with the user `3`.